# Cannot Download Google Play Services SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, google-play-services

I am using eclipse ADT and am attempting to download the Google Play Services SDK, but this SDK does not appear within the SDK manager; How can I get this to appear?

Comment: I tried that solution, and it did not work.

Comment: my bad then.. apologies.